# Changing Row Colours on DevExpress GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I am trying to change the colour of a row to green in a devexpress gridview. When searching I found many examples of how to do this... in websites BUT this is a windows application. I cannot find any thing on a windows application so can someone please help me out a bit here.

I simply just want to change the colour of a single row to green.

Forgot to mention, its a C# application.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean the background colour or the forecolour?

Comment: backcolour, but forecolour will help later so actualy both

Comment: design time or runtime?

Comment: when I click a button, I want it to change colour. I'm guessing that means runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For changing the row colour in runtime handle the RowStyle event:

```
    public Color color1;
    public Color color2;
    public int rowhandle;

    private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.RowHandle == rowhandle)
            {
                if (color1 != null && color2 != null)
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = color1;
                    e.Appearance.BackColor2 = color2;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        color1 = Color.BurlyWood;
        color2 = Color.DarkOrchid;
        rowhandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
        gridView1.RefreshRow(rowhandle);
    }
```

The code bellow will maintain the colour:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Color color1;
    public Color color2;
    public int rowhandle;
    public List<int> rowhandles;

    private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rowhandles.Any(x=>x==e.RowHandle))
            {
                if (color1 != null && color2 != null)
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = color1;
                    e.Appearance.BackColor2 = color2;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        color1 = Color.BurlyWood;
        color2 = Color.DarkOrchid;
        rowhandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
        if (!rowhandles.Any(x => x == rowhandle))
            rowhandles.Add(rowhandle);
        gridView1.RefreshRow(rowhandle);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> l = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        l.Add(1,"one");
        l.Add(2,"two");
        l.Add(3,"three");
        l.Add(4, "four");
        l.Add(5, "five");
        l.Add(6, "six");
        l.Add(7, "seven");
        l.Add(8, "eight");
        l.Add(9, "nine");

        gridControl1.DataSource = l.ToList();

        rowhandles = new List<int>();
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you choose which row? I have a solution but i need to know more.

Comment: I use gridView1.FocusedRowHandle to determine which row was last clicked on before clicking the button to change the colour

Comment: I am going to mark you as the answer because you helped me to find a solution and also you helped me a lot, thanks. Your solution here looks like it should work but I am going to stick to the one I figured out with your help. again thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad i could be of any help. It would be nice if you could post your solution for further reference.

Comment: I was looking for this solution for over a hour ! thanks very much

Comment: @Giannis Paraskevopoulos I can not find words grand enough to say thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following simple solution:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
//...
gridControl1.DataSource = new List<DataObj> {
    new DataObj(){ ID=0, Name="A" },
    new DataObj(){ ID=1, Name="B" },
    new DataObj(){ ID=2, Name="C" },
    new DataObj(){ ID=3, Name="D" },
};
gridView1.CustomDrawCell += gridView1_CustomDrawCell;
//...
void gridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e) {
    if(selectedRowHandle.GetValueOrDefault(GridControl.InvalidRowHandle) == e.RowHandle) {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
int? selectedRowHandle;
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int prevSelectedRowHandle = selectedRowHandle.GetValueOrDefault(GridControl.InvalidRowHandle);
    if(prevSelectedRowHandle != GridControl.InvalidRowHandle)
        gridView1.RefreshRow(prevSelectedRowHandle); // reset row-style to default
    selectedRowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
    gridView1.InvalidateRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle); // row painting request
}
```

This solution is based on the [GridView.CustomDrawCell](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) event that is preferred when it is only needed to change some specific row appearance. It also works for currently selected row rather then [GridView.RowCellStyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic).

Related help topic: [Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758)