# DevExpress GridView Row Color

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

Anyone here knows how to accomplish this kind of rows using DevExpress GridView on WinForms?

[image: gridview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go through documentation for the topic: [Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758).

You can do this using various ways:

1. [Customizing Appearances](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758)
2. Using the [GridView.CustomDrawCell](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) event

> The GridView.RowStyle event can be handled to customize the appearance
>   of individual rows in GridViews. To customize a specific cell's
>   appearance, handle the GridView.RowCellStyle event instead. The
>   GridView.RowStyle event fires before the GridView.RowCellStyle event.

Example:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, 
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e) {
   GridView View = sender as GridView;
   if(e.RowHandle >= 0) {
      string category = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["Category"]);
      if(category == "Beverages") {
         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
         e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.SeaShell;
      }            
   }
}
```

**References:**
[Changing Row Colours on DevExpress GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188525/changing-row-colours-on-devexpress-gridview?rq=1)

Hope this help..

Answer (score 0):

You click on GridView and then click on Theme, you can choose from this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback but i ain't looking for the theme, i'm looking to change the row colors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do in a DataGridView control in forms. Should be similar I assume, it has been a while since I last used DevExpress. But you should go through the DevExpress' documentation, since all of the components are very well documented.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgInformation.Rows)
{
    if (some criteria here == 1234)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Goldenrod;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
gridView.EnableAppearanceEvenRow = true;
```

Or:

```
gridView.EnableAppearanceOddRow = true;
```