# How to change the row color based on certain column values with devexpress?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a Devexpress gridview. I need to change the color of the entire row based on certain values in multiple columns. I have a category column, onHand column and a TrackLevel column. The colors are set out as below:

*Stock Item with stock Track Levels on: White*

*Stock item no stock track levels on: Pienk/maroon/red (depending on screen quality)*

*Service item track levels off: Blue – if category is marked as service*

*Service item track levels on: Pienk/maroon/red (depending on screen quality) – if category is marked as service*

*Service item track levels off: Pienk/maroon/red (depending on screen quality) – if category is not marked as service*

*Grouped stock item: Green*

*Stock item track levels off: Yellow*

I can use the **Devexpress Designer** but it does not allow me to evaluate the values of multiple columns.

I have visited https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t621755/change-the-color-of-a-row-or-cell but there is no **RowStyleEventArgs** when I type it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DevExpress GridView Row Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045342/devexpress-gridview-row-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handled the gridview.rowstyle event and it worked. Example code below:

```
Private Sub MyGridView_RowStyle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RowStyleEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowStyle
            Dim category As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "CategoryID"))

            If category = 1 Then
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red
            Else
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            End If

            e.HighPriority = True   'override any other formatting  
        End Sub
```