# Changing Row Back Color on DevExpress GridView on condition

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have two grid view and a button on a click of button I copy data from gridView1 to gridView2
This is my code:

```
private async void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)

        {
            DataRow rowGridView1 = (gridView1.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as DataRowView).Row;
            for (int j = 0; j < gridView3.RowCount; j++)
            {
                if (rowGridView1["BS"].ToString() == gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "ProjectN").ToString() &&
                    rowGridView1["Repère"].ToString() == gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "Parts").ToString())
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row[0] = rowGridView1["BS"];
                    row[1] = gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "Parts");
                    row[2] = gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "Profile");
                    row[3] = rowGridView1["Quantité"];

                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                else if(j == (gridView3.RowCount -1)) 
                {
                    gridView1.RowStyle += (senderr, ee) => {

                        if (gridView1.GetFocusedDataRow() == rowGridView1)
                        {
                            ee.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            ee.HighPriority = true;
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to change the back color of gridView1 rows that do not match the condition so i can verified them
Unfortunately, all rows become red.
how can I fix this problem.
Thanks in advance

[Answer by Giannis Paraskevopoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18188865/9608194)

Answer (score 0):

Here code modified, it is done with notepad and it remains the test.

First the background color of gridview1 that must be changed according to the values ​​of "BS" and "repère", this is done in the RowStyle function.

```
private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, RowStyleEventArgs e)  {  

    If (e.RowHandle = this.gridView1.FocusedRowHandle)  
    {
       string strBS = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(row, "BS");
       string strRepere = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(row, "Repère");
        if (SearchRow(strBS,strRepere)==true)
         {
           e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red  
           e.HighPriority = True  
          }
    }
}

private bool SearchRow(string strBS, string strRepere)  {  
    bool RowExist=false;
    for (int j = 0; j < gridView3.RowCount; j++)
    {
      if (gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "ProjectN").ToString() ==strBS &&
        gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "Parts").ToString()==strRepere)
      {
         RowExist=true;
         Break;
      }
    }
   return RowExist;    
}
```

Adding gridview1 Rows to gridview3

```
private async void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int[] selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow rowGridView1 = (gridView1.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as DataRowView).Row;
            for (int j = 0; j < gridView3.RowCount; j++)
            {
                if (rowGridView1["BS"].ToString() == gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "ProjectN").ToString() &&
                    rowGridView1["Repère"].ToString() == gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "Parts").ToString())
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row[0] = rowGridView1["BS"];
                    row[1] = gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "Parts");
                    row[2] = gridView3.GetRowCellValue(j, "Profile");
                    row[3] = rowGridView1["Quantité"];

                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }
       }

       gridView1.Datasource=dt;
       grid.DataBind();
}
```